# Get difference between TIMESTAMPs in MySQL and update another Column

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, sql-update, timestamp

I have 2 columns in MySQL db with datatype as `TIMESTAMP`.
For every row I want to store the difference between the these 2 timestamps in `hh:mm:ss` (hh might exceed 24 or might also be 3 digits) into another column.

What should I use for this?

I tried this but it is not working.

```
update ABC_TABLE set colC=TIMEDIFF(colA, colB);
```

`colC` is of Type `TIME`

```
|Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| colC                   | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

Comment: Add your table records to the question along with the outcome of your `update` query results.

Comment: also post `show create table abc_table` results.

Comment: @RavinderReddy The question is perfectly fine without this information.

Comment: Please add sample records along with desired output.

Comment: @fancyPants: I understand. But when OP says the update is not working, I think we need to check what the actual structure is and sample records are.

Answer (score 0):

The hour part of the time datatype can't hold values larger than 23. You'll have to use char or varchar.

Calculate the difference between the two timestamps in seconds, like this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-06-10 11:00:00', '2016-06-10 12:00:00');
```

Then you can use this function to convert the seconds into the format `days:hours:minutes:seconds`

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_s2dhms;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION f_s2dhms(v_seconds INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
DETERMINISTIC
COMMENT 'converts seconds in days:hours:minutes:seconds'
BEGIN
DECLARE v_dhms VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE v_days INT;
DECLARE v_hours INT;
DECLARE v_minutes INT;

SET v_hours = v_seconds/3600;
SET v_minutes = (v_seconds % 3600) / 60;
SET v_seconds = (v_seconds % 3600) % 60;

IF (v_hours > 23) THEN
    SET v_days = v_hours / 24;
    SET v_hours = v_hours % 24;
ELSE
    SET v_days = 0;
END IF;

RETURN CONCAT(v_days, ':', RIGHT(CONCAT('0', v_hours), 2), ':', RIGHT(CONCAT('0', v_minutes), 2), ':', RIGHT(CONCAT('0', v_seconds), 2));

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Use it like

```
SELECT f_s2dhms(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-06-10 11:00:00', '2016-06-10 12:00:00'));
```

- [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) you can read more about `timestampdiff()`